# URL blocked error in Facebook OAuth

Tags: java, facebook, oauth, facebook-oauth

I am implementing Facebook OAuth on my localhost where I made following configuration :

1) Setting(Basic) :

- Domain   : localhost
- Site URL : http://localhost:9090/Facebook_Login/fbhome

Where I have changed the tomcat port to 9090 & "fbhome" is servlet which               displays some information like name, gender, email after successful implementation

2) In Facebook Login section :

- Valid OAuth redirect url :http://localhost:8080/Facebook_Login/fbhome

But I encountered 2 errors as mentioned below :

1. The requested URL /Facebook_Login/fbhome was not found on this server.
2. URL Blocked: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not
   whitelisted in the app’s Client OAuth Settings. Make sure Client and Web OAuth Login are on and add all your app domains as Valid OAuth Redirect URIs.

Please can anyone correct me if I have done any mistake in my configuration. It would be nice if I got proper solution. Because I googled a lot but couldn't find exact solution for it.

Comment: Well the first one, the 404 not found, is definitively something on your end; so you gotta fix your routing to make that URL available first of all. Btw., I would recommend against a setup that uses non-standard ports, that can cause problems with Facebook login. Use ports 80/443, if possible. (I never understood why people chose other ports for the dev environment setup in the first place. Having it mimic the later live environment as closely as possible is always a good idea - so why introduce more friction, by choosing non-standard ports for HTTP(S) …?)

Comment: @CBroe Well i tried using 8080 but i got same error again

Comment: If you are still getting the 404 from your own system, then that is not a Facebook problem.

Comment: @CBroe I mean 404 error has gone actually as per your suggestion i keep port to 8080, Only error now is second one

Comment: But you did update the Valid OAuth Redirect URIs setting as well, right? // As I said, I would recommend a test setup using default ports …

Comment: Hey @CBroe  I followed your suggestions, And its working totally fine. Thank you so much

Answer (score -1):

first you need to register to your application with call back URL, then you will get the appId and SecretId.Use those Id's and call FB OAuth url with you callbackURL

Comment: I already registered my app & i have both appId & SecretId . Any it is giving me those errors on when i tried on localhost. Previously i tried to using callback url as "http://www.google.com" and it works fine @chandran